Web development with Flask: can't seem to correctly render HTML templates
I'm coding a web app with Flask, I've encountered the following problem. I already coded my template in HTML, defined its route (which supposedly returns the HTML template), and defined the url prefix in the __init__ script. I'm quite new to HTML and flask, I don't know if I forgot to write something, but I go over and over and nothing seems to work.
The website does properly execute, I've created buttons on the Home Page in order to access the different routes, but it just displays the base HTML template, and not the additional HTML markup I wrote in it. I will copy some of the code in order to make it clearer:
auth.py:
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

login.html:
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Login{% endblock %} {%block 
    content %}
    <h1>This is the Login page</h1>
    {% endblock %}

So this just renders the base.html, it doesn't extend it to also show the message.
I tried to code different routes in a webpage using templates, and it doesn't seem to display the extension added.
Edit: here is the base.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbar"
        >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Login</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>


Also show your base.html

And since you are using blueprints, make sure you are doing that right. For example, following tutorials such as this one: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-blueprints-to-organize-flask-apps/

@topsail thank you for the tip, I will be sure to check some tutorials out, if also added the base.html in case that helps with solving my issue

It seems to me that the definition for a block named content is missing in the base.html file. As you did for the title, you define a block named in the template, whose content will later be overwritten by the block of the same name in the extending template. Take a look at the "Template Inheritance" section of the Flask documentation.

First of all, you are missing the content block (as @Detlef mentioned) in your base.html. Add it like this:
<!-- Your code before -->
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      {% block content %}{% endblock %} <!-- Add this line -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    <script>

<!-- Your code after -->

Second, you need to register your blueprint before you can use it in your application. Your code will look somewhat like this:
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')
@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

app.register_blueprint(auth)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Ideally, it would be better to put the blueprint into another file, but that is only for ease of use, not required.
After applying these changes, this is what you get on http://127.0.0.1:5000/login:

